# Indentação em um TEdit

Tags: delphi

É possível indentar um texto dentro de um `TEdit` ou um componente derivado (ex. `TLabeledEdit`)? Se sim, como?
Não quero alinhá-lo (*Esquerda, Centro, Direita*), quero apenas indentá-lo, como se fosse a primeira linha de um parágrafo.

A aplicação é `VCL`, não `FireMonkey`.
`Delphi XE7`.

Comment: Jogar um tab no inicio ?

Comment: Basicamente isso @VictorZanella um `Tab` ou um `Espaço` geraria o efeito desejado, mas gostaria de obter esse efeito sem inserir um caractere.

Comment: Entendi, qual seu objetivo com isso ? Visto que o TEdit costuma ter apenas uma linha.

Comment: @VictorZanella Na verdade quero aplicar esse efeito no componente `TLabeledEdit`, sendo que o `TLabel` ficaria acima do `TEdit`. Visto que o formulário em questão tem muitos campos, o efeito que solicito ajudaria o usuário a visualizar as informações.

Comment: Entendi, estou tentando aplicar um tratamento similar ao do Paragraph.FirstIndent do RichEdit. Dá uma olhada nesse cara.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Você pode enviar uma mensagem para o componente modificando sua margem!

Tente algo assim:

```
LabeledEdit1.Perform(EM_SETMARGINS, EC_LEFTMARGIN or EC_RIGHTMARGIN, MakeLParam(20, 0));
```

O `MakeLParam` precisa de 2 parâmetros inteiros, o primeiro corresponde ao lado esquerdo e o segundo corresponde ao lado direito!

Serve para o `TEdit` também!

Comment: Essa é nova pra mim, bela sacada. +1

Comment: ;) esse `Perform` é semelhante ao `SendMessage`, compartilhando vamos aprendendo mais.